Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'msg' was corrupted in File IO
I wrote a simple program to test file IO; however, an exception "Run-Time Check Failure #2" from variable 'msg' was throwed every time the program terminates. Other than that, the file IO seems to work fine, at least superficially.
Google around find me many similar threads, but none of the info solve my issue.
My code:
        FILE* fp = fopen(fname, "a+");

    std::string response{ "Hello World!\n" };
    const char* cstr = response.c_str();

    int loop{ 0 };

    while (loop < 10)
    {
        fwrite(cstr, 1, strlen(cstr), fp);
        int lenMsg = strlen(cstr);

        fseek(fp, -(lenMsg+1), SEEK_CUR);
        char msg[](bufLen, 0);
        const size_t ret_code = fread(msg, 1, lenMsg, fp);
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

        for (int i{ 0 }; i < lenMsg; i++)
            std::cout << msg[i];
                
        loop++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

I have try to use try-catch block, or modify the length of data extracted using fread to no avail.

Try to investigate sizeof(msg). This will be a great hint.

What is char msg[](bufLen, 0) supposed to do? What is bufLen?

const int bufLen{ 100 };
char msg[](bufLen, 0)  is a char array that is used to hold readouts from fread.
The purpose of this short program is to test fwrite and immediately followed by fread simutaneously.

Thanks for the clue on sizeof, investigate that now.

You should prefer std::fstream over FILE, although that is not related to your bug.

@user65535 "The purpose of this short program is to test fwrite and immediately followed by fread simutaneously." -- No, the purpose of your real program is to do that. The purpose of the code in the question is to demonstrate "an exception "Run-Time Check Failure #2" from variable 'msg'". This is two-fold. First, it should be minimal, with unnecessary steps removed. (E.g., can you reproduce without looping?) Second, it should be complete enough for someone to copy-compile-run (without reading the comments). See [mre].

"I have try to use try-catch block," -- See Try-Catch doesn't catch exception. Even though what you see might be called an exception, it's not an exception in the C++ sense.

@JaMiT Thanks for the info, will keep future questions conformed to stanfard.

@user65535 "will keep future questions conformed to stanfard" -- Is there any particular reason you don't improve the current question? Questions on Stack Overflow are not merely for the person who wrote them. Ideally, each question stands for eternity, enlightening all future visitors with the same question. So improving questions after they are answered (as long as this does not invalidate an answer) is worth the time.

char msg[](bufLen, 0); isn't an array of bufLen size with elements initialized to 0 (rules of direct initialization since C++20). It is an array of 2 elements: [bufLen, 0]. If you decide to use C++, then start using C++ library and take std::vector instead, it has the desired syntax: std::vector<char> vec(bufLen, 0);.
Not related to your bug, but also get rid of FILE*, fwrite, fseek, and use  fstream. More (recommended) resources for beginners: learncpp.

Thanks a lot! I mistake the syntax of vector for array.
